# Golf a recursive web crawler

Tags: code-golf

## Challenge

Create a program that will build a recursive list of all linked webpages (given a starting point), to a depth determined by user input.
*Any valid link in the HTML should be crawled, whether or not it is a script, image, etc.*

## Example Input

```
<program name> <url to crawl> <depth>
webcrawler http://crawlthissite.com/mypage.html 2
```

## Example Output

```
http://crawlthissite.com/book1
http://crawlthissite.com/book2
http://crawlthissite.com/book1/1.html
http://crawlthissite.com/book2/1.html
http://site.net
http://coolsite.com/
http://coolsite.com/about.html
http://coolsite.com/shop.html
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

P.S. this is my first code-golf, please don't get mad if I have broken the rules of the site in any way, please just let me know.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Try posting in the [Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) to receive feedback on answers before posting on the main site.

Comment: Parsing HTML and deciding what a "valid" link is is a very complex subject, which would need to be described in much more detail to make a challenge.